# add_cap for editor but no admin role

Tags: admin, user-roles, profiles

I want my editors to have the possibility, to add other users.
I added:

```
    $edit_editor->add_cap('create_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('delete_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('edit_users');
```

to the functions.php - but now, the editors are also able to create, change an Admin Role.

Is there any way, to exclude admin from the roles?

Thank you!

AD

Answer (score 3):

Giving the capability to delete and edit users would compromise your security, as then the editors would have the ability to modify your profile too. What you could do is just give the `create_users` capability to the editors. But the users thus created would be allotted "Subscribers" role by deafult.

**EDIT:**
Try the following code ( Requires a bit of testing / sort of a hack for your requirement )

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['user_id'] ) ) {
    $userdata = get_user_by( 'id', $_REQUEST['user_id'] );
    if ( isset( $userdata->roles[0] ) && ( 'administrator' == $userdata->roles[0] ) ) {
        $edit_editor->remove_cap( 'create_users' );
        $edit_editor->remove_cap( 'delete_users' );
        $edit_editor->remove_cap( 'edit_users' );
    } else {
        $edit_editor->add_cap( 'create_users' );
        $edit_editor->add_cap( 'delete_users' );
        $edit_editor->add_cap( 'edit_users' );
    }
} else {
    $edit_editor->add_cap( 'create_users' );
    $edit_editor->add_cap( 'delete_users' );
    $edit_editor->add_cap( 'edit_users' );
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for the reply. Is there any way to make not "Subscribers" by default, but "Authors"? Maybe that would be just enough...

Comment: Just try the above edited answer and see if it fulfills the requirement

Comment: thank you for your effort! I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you using `$edit_editor = get_role('editor')` to fetch the editor role? From the above code you should be able to assign any role to a new user but you can't edit existing users.